# Angularjs: ng-class and CSS animations (running only once)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

I am an AngularJS newbie so please be patient.

First, the code. Here's the relevant .html part:

```
<span ng-class="{'error-text': true, 'animated-error': vm.email_error}" ng-show="vm.email_error" translate>EMAIL_ERROR</span>
```

The .scss part:

```
    .error-text{
      position: absolute;
      &.animated-error{
        animation: bigandnormal 2s;
      }
    }
```

And there is a .js that is modifying vm.email_error after a click:

```
var validateEmail = function(){
  var isEmailValid = /(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(vm.email);
  vm.email_error = !isEmailValid;
  return isEmailValid;
};
```

A button click runs the `validateEmail()` function.
What happens here is that when I perform the first click (with an invalid email) the class is added correctly to the span and the animation runs.

But if I click again, the animation is NOT run again.
Looking at the inspector, it seems that the class in never added again.
I have even tried to reset `vm.email_error` to `false` in the first line of the `validateEmail()` function and removed the `animated-error` from the console before clicking again:

```
angular.element(".error-text").each(function(index, el) {
    angular.element(el).removeClass('animated-error'); 
});
```

But I cannot see anymore the animation and the class.

But in any case I do not think I am not doing it the right way, there should be a way to accomplish this.

This is what I am asking you :)

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: I if put `vm.email_error = !isEmailValid;` in a `setTimeout` it works properly. It would be great to have an explanation from someone who knows that technology. Of course, it is clear that this cannot be the real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your email_error variable as a $scope or $rootScope variable rather than as a controller variable.

```
var validateEmail = function(){
  var isEmailValid = /(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(vm.email);
  $scope.email_error = !isEmailValid; // or $rootScope.email_error = !isEmailValid;
  return isEmailValid;
};
```

And you don't need the quotes around your css class name.

Then call it in your html without prefixes, like this:

```
<span ng-class="{error-text: true, animated-error: email_error}" ng-show="email_error" translate='EMAIL_ERROR'></span>
```

Also, be careful on how to use angular translate :

1. If you use it as a directive, you have to write it as

   ```
   <p translate='MY_TRAD'></p>
   ```
2. If you use it as a filter, then it's

   ```
   <p>{{ 'MY_TRAD' | translate }}</p>
   ```

(angular translate doc: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate)

Comment: thanks for your answer and your tips, anyway it does not work. Please take a look at the UPDATE on the original question if you can.